# Difficulty Rating system for questions - my proposed solution

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I love SO but as I become a more proficient programmer I find it harder to find questions that I feel 'worthy' of answering - many agree with me as per previous suggestions on this subject.

(I don't mean that in a big headed way I just mean there are loads of people who can answer them so I don't see the point - I want to be challenged! Conversely I don't want to see questions at 20+ years experience level as I can't answer them!)

It would be nice to have an additional option next to

```
share|edit|flag| **complexity**
```

This then opens a rating option

**A spreadsheet** better explaining this is located on [google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP1hd7cUQ3z3lXTBMQ8P_KoZjASQWoW3C5rwX3i6v70/edit?usp=sharing)

Spreadsheet is hopefully self explanatory -> coloured items are either editable or calculated values that are relevant.

**QUICK CLAIRTY**

I haven't made a clear distinction:-

USERS (me and you) get a 'score' - call it 'experience score'.

This experience score is based on questions we vote upon.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

**I** might have an experience score of -1.

**You** might have an experience score of +2.

Lets also assume for the maths we have both only **cast 1 vote before.**

We BOTH VOTE on the same question on its COMPLEXITY *(nothing to do with quality)*

I might vote 'challenging' and you might vote 'easy'

Other votes may be collated for the question and the question has been given an average of 0.5 'COMPLEXITY' by the community

I would get 0.5 (community complexity) - 1 (Challenging) -> which gives me -0.5 as my 'difference'

So my NEW EXPERIENCE SCORE would be -1 (existing) **+** -0.5 (from this question) / 2 (number of questions I have voted on) = -0.75 -> my new experience rating.

Similarly for you we would have

0.5 (community complexity) - -1 (Easy) -> which gives you +1.5 as your 'difference'

+2 (existing) + 1.5 (from this question) / 2 (number of questions you have voted on) = +1.75 -> your new experience rating.

We then use the experience ratings to find questions that fall into our 'bracket'

So I would see questions with a complexity rating of -1.25 to -0.25 (=- 0.5 on my experience level of -0.75)

However you would see questions with a complexity range of 1.25 to 2.25 (from your experience level of 1.75)

**NOTES**

The system would be a 'hidden' rating -> so there is no incentive to mark everything as 'very easy' to gain status.

The system ends up self-regulating because if some troll marks everything as 'very easy' that questions difficulty score will increase -> then none-trolls will mark it as too hard!

A quick run-down

I mark a question as easy - the questions score is +0.5 from the community votes so far so I get (0.5 - -1 = 1.5 added to my score) (score of question - my rating for the question)

I get shown questions between 1 and 2 difficulty. (my score +- 5)

I mark the next question as hard and the average score is 1.2 so I get (1.2 - +1 = 0.2)

MY AVERAGE is now 0.85

so I get shown questions between 0.35 and 1.35 difficulty

Over maybe 7-10 votes I might average out with 1.2 as my score.

I will get shown questions that have votes between 0.7 and 1.7 difficulty.

**As a further measure the system for adding questions is simple.**

If my rating is currently 1.2 then any question I ask starts at 1.2 difficulty - it is likely to end up in the correct bracket (as if I can't do it then I would say it is not a trivial question)

NEW USERS - start them at -1 -> they will quickly end up in the correct bracket and so will their questions.

**OTHER POINTS**

Education isn't difficult - after a person has viewed 5 questions without commenting / answering just show a quick notification saying 'did you know rating items will find you questions you want to answer'

Additionally if someone DOES answer a question we could add that questions complexity score to their score average - meaning that over time they will fall in the correct bracket even without voting!

As I improve - so will the questions that I get asked meaning I will get pushed still even if I do eventually become good (not there yet :-P)

Obviously it isn't perfect - but I think it would work well enough to encourage higher level users to take the time - without penalising new users.

**FINAL THOUGHT**

This is a 'switch on, switch off' option -> sometimes I might want to answer easy questions or just have a look around!

Thoughts? (I am now prepared for the barrage of 'you are an idiot comments' :-P hehe)

**SPREADSHEET EXPLANATION**

This is the easiest way to explain it as you can 'follow along'

The spreadsheet illustrates 4 fictional questions.

A - the 'vote' that can be applied - from very easy to too challenging.

C - is the vote that *I* gave the question - based on how I found it.

E - these are the votes of others that have gone before me - the yellow box is just a count of total votes.

F - these are arbitrary numbers - an easy question gets a -3 a hard one +3

G - Average score calculation -> only the value in blue below the yellow (G12, G25 etc.) is relevant - this is the average score the question has received from the community.

I - Just a filler column to hold 'my score' -> the yellow box contains my score

J - MY DIFFERENCE -> this my relative complexity for that question and is based on average score (i.e. G12) MINUS 'My score' for that question (i.e. I10)

L - this is calculated as a 'is between Q12 and R12' -> which are calculated as +- 0.5 from )12 -> my average score difference.

'My average score difference' is just Average of column J.

O - my average differences score is the relevant one -> 012 -> it is used to decide the 'range' that I fall in. This +- 0.5 is used against EACH QUESTIONS average score (G12 for example) to decide whether it falls within my experience range.

Hopefully that is more clear but I am more than happy to explain further.

Comment: Asking people to download and open a file directly from your website is very sketchy. You couldn't inline it, or added it to something that people could trust, like Google Docs? Or add it as a picture? Also, what is the point of locking a spreadsheet if there's no password to the lock? This is ***not*** self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments cupcake - I didn't know etiquette for uploading / showing spreadsheets as I haven't done it before - I will google docs it! As with regards to locks it is just that items you can edit are unlocked -> but if someone wants to fiddle / delete locked cells I wanted them to know they could by just unlocking the sheet under 'review'

Comment: have edit the question to have the spreadsheet hosted on google docs -> it has slightly messed up the formatting but still works

Comment: As it is written, I do not understand your proposed rating system at all, and the spreadsheet does not help much either. This is not as self-explanatory as you think it is, you need to add much more details and examples. (Though beware of adding too much details without also adding some short summaries.)

Comment: ok @HugoRune I will attempt to re-write it with a better explanation. Is there a particular part that is unclear or is it just the whole thing :-P

Comment: **Why do we need ratings at all**? Question quality has nothing to do with how hard a problem is. Most of all, 'difficulty' is extremely subjective.

Comment: I can't really narrow it down, sorry :) I think I am missing the basic premise here, do you want to attach "difficulty" scores to questions or to users? What does "hidden rating" mean, and what are the dangers you seem to address in your notes?

Comment: hehe - I have added spreadsheet explanation. "difficulty" to questions BUT use those difficulty scores to establish a base 'Experience Level' for each user - we then match question difficulty to experience level. "Hidden Rating" just means - you can't see the rating of the question or your own rating -> it is not something like the up/downvote system. The dangers hopefully become more clear now after addressing those points (but you never know - it makes sense in my little world :-P)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters - my explanation is obviously poorly worded - I am not rating question QUALITY - I want to rate question COMPLEXITY. As you said 'difficulty' is subjective -> my proposal is designed to address that -> for example you might think a question is easy, I might think it is hard -> my system addresses this by giving **you** a level of '2' (arbitrary number) and **me** a rating of -1 -> if a **question** of difficulty 1 came up then you should find it easy(ish) but I should find it challenging.

Comment: My point was: what problem are you trying to address here?

Comment: That bit is about the only clear bit as I address it at the very beginning - doesn't matter voted to close my own question :-D Thanks for having a look peeps it just seems I cannot get the point across :-(

Comment: see [How about a difficulty rating for questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions) and about 10,000 questions linked to it (at MSE)

Comment: I totally agree with you @GrahamRitchie see [my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337898/how-to-generate-some-lists-of-questions-that-should-be-interesting-for-everyone/337899#337899) which is close to yours

Answer (score 8):

This is way too complicated and even if it weren't, it wouldn't work.

Variations on the question complexity idea have been thrown out before but the issue is always the same, "complexity is in the eye of the beholder".  What is complex for me might be simple for you.

So by only showing you questions that meet a specific complexity score (based on what other random users have selected), no one would benefit.

1. You would be missing out on opportunities to answer questions that others have said are complex, but you think are easy
2. The OP would be missing out on views from potential answers just because some arbitrary complexity scheme decided that it was too hard for them to answer.

And a side issue even if it would work, a users skill level likely only applies to specific tags, so the complexity numbers would be skewed based on the questions and answers that the user has decided to answer and not based on their actual skill level.

Comment: I really have not explained myself well - I have addressed all of the points but just cannot get it across - and far from complex the system is simple, self regulating and even covers the tags part as that segregation of skill is already built in with the tagging system - I will leave this alone as it is obvious I am not going to get anywhere explaining this :-( but thanks for having a look peeps

Comment: @GrahamRitchie the fact that it was so difficult to explain suggests it is way to complex.  Something that requires user feedback to work correct needs to be simple so they understand how their feedback is used.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I actually think I get it.  And the issue is still the same. You might find a question easy and I find it hard, but then I find a different question in the same tags easy, and you find it hard, and then we both find 3 more questions equally complex.  The point is no matter how it averages our, you and I will disagree on what is easy and what is hard, so there is no metric that I can think of that would even that out.

Comment: Using it is leave a vote of easy to complex - that bit isn't hard - like I said It requires 3 calculations - it just seems my way of explaining them has 'muddied the water' - it is my explanation that has failed here not the system as I have used something similar elsewhere :-( Like I said thanks for dropping by and having a look but I think we should let this die as I am obviously not very eloquent :-P

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I think @ psubsee2003 didn't get the power of democraty and voting : if 3 users with 2000+ reputation think a question deserves to be classified as "advanced" then it means obviously it is **not** a beginner question